# Upgrading to vue 3.4+ causes useRoute to be undefined inside computed

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, computed-properties

I have code like this. It generates tabs object for my components

```
export function generateRouterTabs (tabs?: RouteRecordRaw[] | undefined, tabsName?: string): {
  name: string
  tabs: IRouterTab[]
} {
  const route = useRoute()

  const mappedName = tabsName || route.name as string | undefined || ''

  const mappedTabs = (tabs || route.matched.find(route => {
    return route.name === route.meta.parentName
  })?.children) || []

  return {
    name: mappedName,
    tabs: mappedTabs.map(_route => ({
      label: _route.meta?.label || '',
      routeName: _route.name as string,
      appComponentID: _route.meta?.appComponentId
    }))
  }
}
```

Inside of script:setup of one of those components, I wrap this function call in a computed property like this:

`const tabs = computed(() => generateRouterTabs())`

It fails with an error, saying

`Cannot read properties of undefined, reading 'name'`

and points to this line of code

`const mappedName = tabsName || **route.name** as string | undefined || ''`.

I've tried using optional chaining, but that breaks the app and does not return any tabs or a name.
Also I tried to pass tabs and tabsName as arguments and it did work. Though, the project is quite big and I wouldn't want to refactor it everywhere, especially if the bug comes from the vue dev team.

To remind you, it's only after I upgrade vue to 3.4+. The project exists for about 2 years and this was not a problem before.

Be very grateful for any assistance.

Also, you can ask me for any additional info that might help you look into the problem deeper.

Comment: At a glance, it's not obvious which one of 3.4's changes would be responsible for the change in your code's outcome. I'm tempted to think the code is run sooner than it used to, in the component's lifecycle and, for some reason, `useRoute()` returns `undefined` at that point. A workaround would be to run your code inside `onMounted`. Please note this is only a hunch, which is why I only commented, instead of providing an answer. As a side-note, you have bigger chances of getting a useful answer on Vue's discord channel. Once you do get an answer, you might want to post it here, for visibility.